# How can i fix this if statement? My last condition seems to break it but I'm not sure why

Tags: python

```py
ip_address = input().split(".")

if ip_address[0] >= 0 and ip_address[0].isnumeric() and ip_address[0] <=255:
    print("Valid first byte")
else:
    print("Invalid first byte")
```

In this code, when I add my final condition of `ip_address[0] <=255` I always get my byte as invalid even though it would technically fit those parameters. For example, I've tried inputs 0 and 127 but they come up as invalid, but if I remove the last condition they are valid. Where am I going wrong?

I've tried putting it as `ip_address[0] < 256` but this hasn't worked either.

Comment: You need to convert it to a number first: `0 <= int(ip_address[0]) < 256`

Answer (score 3):

The value returned by `input()` is always a string. When you use `.split('.')` you then get a list of strings.

To test the range of the number you will need to convert it to `int` first, but even before that you can use the numeric check:

```py
ip_address = input().split(".")

if ip_address[0].isnumeric() and (0 <= int(ip_address[0]) <= 255):
    print("Valid first byte")
else:
    print("Invalid first byte")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ip_address = input().split(".")
print(ip_address)

if ip_address[0].isnumeric() and int(ip_address[0]) >= 0 and int(ip_address[0] )<=255:
    print("Valid first byte")
else:
    print("Invalid first byte")


Try this

when you input some ip address: 192.168.2.3
['192'.'168'.'2'.'3'] it will be converted to list of strings .
you cannot compare strings with numbers . so you have to convert 
string to int  to compare.
```

Comment: You are going to get a runtime error with: `int(ip_address[0])` if it is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
ip_address = int(input().split(".")[0])

if ip_address >= 0 and ip_address <=255:
    print("Valid first byte")
else:
    print("Invalid first byte")
```

Explanation: It first coverts the `input()` to `int()` and then it checks for the conditions.
Conclusion: Your code was not converting the `input()` to `int()` and that is the main reason for the error!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are testing a string (e.g. `"255"`) with and integer (`255`) and that is why your test is failing.

It might also we useful to separate the requesting input from the testing of the inputted value.

For example, in the code below the `main()` function is where the code requests input from the user. It will continue to ask until the user enters a correct ip address.

The `is_valid_ip_address` return `None` until the address is valid when it will return a list of the four values.

This allows for easier test (example given) and better error messages for the user.

```py
def is_valid_ip_address(ip_address):
    parts = ip_address.split(".")
    # is numeric
    if not all([part.isnumeric() for part in parts]):
        print("Error: Not all parts are numeric values")
        return
    # Test there are four parts
    if len(parts) != 4:
        print("Error: There needs to be four parts to the ip address")
        return
    # convert parts to integer for easy comparison
    parts = list(map(int, parts))
    # Test all parts in valid range
    for idx, part in enumerate(parts):
        if not 0 < part < 255:
            print(f"Error: Part {idx + 1} is not in valid range")
            return
    return parts


def run_tests():
    test_values = [
        "192.168.2.300",
        "192.168.2.3",
        "192.168",
        "dave"
    ]
    for test_ip in test_values:
        print(f"\nTesting: {test_ip}")
        is_valid_ip_address(test_ip)


def main():
    ip_address = None
    while ip_address is None:
        entered_value = input("Enter an IP address: ")
        ip_address = is_valid_ip_address(entered_value)
    print(f"You entered a valid address")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_tests()
    main()
```